# Is it possible to run multible statements in sqlite3 with python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have more than 2 tables in an sqlite3 database. Im trying to INSERT data into one table and update a few columns in another table. Is that possible?

I have tried to user executemany() and executescript() in many shapes and forms. I have recieved a bunch of error messages, and its mostly because execute will not accept my parameters.

```py
with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.executescript("""INSERT INTO prev_users (
                                imei_prev,
                                user_id_prev,
                                start_date,
                                end_date,
                                type_prev)
                               VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);
                               UPDATE phones
                                SET owner = (?), date = (?), state = (?)
                                WHERE imei = (?);
                               """,(user['imei'], user['user_id'], user['date'], date, user['type'], "None", date, "In Progress", user['imei']))
```

Answer (score 0):

`executescript()` will not accept parameters because, well, it doesn't take parameters as an argument, it only takes a "script". From [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executescript):

> **executescript(sql_script)**
>
> This is a nonstandard convenience method for executing multiple SQL statements at once. It issues a COMMIT statement first, then
>   executes the SQL script it gets as a parameter.
>
> sql_script can be an instance of str.

For example, it might be used for creating several tables in one script.

[`executemany()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) runs one sql against a sequence of parameters.

Neither method is the right tool for the job. You'll likely have to split it into two calls to `execute()`.